# MySQL query shows something like 0x8081 instead of special characters

Tags: mysql, sql, database, character-encoding

When i run `SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137);`

I got `0x80818283848586878889` istead of `Çüéâäàåçêë`.

Does anybody know why?

I'm using charset `utf8mb4`.

When I run `show variables like '%char%';` I got

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name                        | Value                          |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client                 | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_connection             | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_database               | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem             | binary                         |
| character_set_results                | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_server                 | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system                 | utf8mb3                        |
| character_sets_dir                   | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1                              |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

I'm using MySQL version 8.0.26

Comment: trying adding ` USING utf8`.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi It does not work. Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING utf8' at line 1

Comment: How did you use the `using utf8`?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi like this: SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137) USING utf8;

Comment: `SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137 USING utf8)` The USING is part of CHAR

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi : i found this query: SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137 USING utf8); but then i got NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output charset is "DOS West European"

Use this query it will display the text in charset "DOS West European"

```
SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137 using cp850)
```

[image]